# Once animated images are off the screen, how do I delete them?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to make a cookie clicker type game and when the screen is clicked, I want to have an animated image fall from the top and off of the screen. I'm pretty sure the images would build up even though I can't see them. There must be a way to delete them once they are off of the screen. Would it be an if statement? Like, once it reaches a certain dimension, remove the image? Help me please. :D

Comment: Seems like you may be after something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately your question is a bit too broad. We can give you more advice if you provide us with your code.

Comment: I don't have any code though. It's just a general question. Removing images completely out of the site once they are off of the screen so it doesn't build up and slow down the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing an "if" condition in your code in which animated image/s fall from the top and off of the screen you can run an independent job which picks the DOM elements/images to be removed based on the condition(hidden images).

```
setInterval(function(){
    //code to select the relevant images based on css class/ other conditions 
    //like position on page etc and then remove them.
    $('img.hidden').remove();
},1000);
```